# jQuery record pagination in div using classic asp

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, asp-classic, recordset

I've been tasked with paginating MySQL query results using Ajax/jQuery rather than in an iFrame. The current iFrame content we use is here: http://www.stratusinternational.com/headerlatest.asp?Page=1&L=EN

The page currently refreshes every 10 seconds, passing (page number +1) until it reaches the end (Page 329). Each page reads in 4 results, and we do include back and next buttons where applicable.

What we want to do is have the same features, but instead of an iFrame, include the results in a div with all the same functionality. I have been searching all night for a solution, but the only one I have found so-far will not support moving to the next page.

The reason behind wanting to change what we do is that the iFrame pagination is recorded in history, so a visitor hitting the browsers back button has to cycle all the way back through iFrame history before the page history.

Apologies if there is no easy solution. Code can be provided if required.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You are probably not going to find any examples that do exactly what you need. You can use the JavaScript setTimeout or setInterval to call a function every 10 seconds and in that use jQuery's AJAX function to call an ASP script that returns the HTML for the 4 properties, and use jQuery's replaceWith method to replace the current content with the new content. You would also have to change the HREF of the page navigation buttons at the same time. It is all quite straight forward to do. Does that help?

Comment: @John Thank you. That does help, and make sense, but I have no experience of jQuery/Ajax to do that part of it. Changing HREF's - I did read somewhere about a command within the HREF so it does not get added to page history - is that what you were referring to?

Regards
Glen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, here's some sample code that should get you started.

You can leave most of your headerlatest.asp script as is but will need to make a few changes and add some JavaScript.

Remove the following line (which is what is reloading the page every 10 seconds). This will be replaced by an AJAX call.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;url=?Page=65&L=EN"/>
```

Give your previous and next buttons IDs:

```
<a id="prev" href="?L=EN&Page=63" style="text-decoration: none"><img src="images/prevframe.png" border="0"></a>

<a id="next" href="?L=EN&Page=65" style="text-decoration: none"><img src="images/nextframe.png" border="0"></a>
```

Give the DIV around the TABLE with the four columns an ID:

```
<div id="content" align="center">
```

Include jQuery on your page and add some JavaScript to handle the refreshing of content and previous/next buttons. You will probably need to make changes to this to suit your needs, such as the part that handles the maximum number of pages.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var page = 1;

    $(".prev").click(function () {
       UpdatePage(-1); 
        return false;
    });

    $(".next").click(function () {
       UpdatePage(1);
        return false;
    });

    function UpdatePage(ctr) {
        if (typeof ctr === "undefined") {
            page = page + 1;
        } else {
            page = page + ctr;
        }
        if (page > 10) //maximum (if needed)
            page = 1; //go to first
        //if (page < 1) //minimum 
        //   page = 10; //go to maximum
        if (page == 1) {
            $("#prev").hide();
            setTimeout(UpdatePage, 1000 * 10);
            return;
        } else {
            $("#prev").show();
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/myservice.asp", //this page needs to return the table content
            data: "{'page':" + page + ",'L':'EN'}",
            contentType: "text/html;",
            cache: false,
            success: function (content) {
                $("#content").html(content);
                setTimeout(UpdatePage, 1000 * 10);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error");
            }
        });
    }

    setTimeout(UpdatePage, 1000 * 10);
});
</script>
```

Lastly you need to create a second script called myservice.asp that has basically most of the code that headerlatest.asp has except it should only return the content inside of that `<div align="center">` with the TABLE inside.

How it works: For the first call your page operates the same as it does now. But after 10 seconds the new content will be requested via AJAX and that will be injected into the content DIV. The previous and next buttons will then also use AJAX to request the appropriate content too.

Let me know how it goes or if you need any help.

Edit:

Don't hide your previous button on page 1 as you do now, instead set it to CSS display:none on page 1 only. The updated JavaScript will take care of the hiding and showing of the previous button now.

```
<a id="prev" href="?L=EN&Page=1" style="display:none;text-decoration: none"><img src="images/prevframe.png" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: Thanks @John. I have implemented your code, but I am not getting any transition/s. What version of jQuery should I be using? I have just got the latest compressed version: jquery-1.11.1.min.js

Is that the right file, and would an incorrect jQuery version be causing the output stay at page 1?

I have renamed the page to http://stratusinternational.com/scrolllatest.asp, as the other page is live on the site, and I prefer to keep this separate till working. 

Would it help if I posted the code on both pages here or eMail to you?

Regards
Glen

Comment: It's my fault: I had an incorrect closing tag in the script. I have updated the answer but the change is the 4th line from the bottom which was `});` but should be just `}`. Also I tried to access your script http://stratusinternational.com/scrolls.asp but it is returning an ASP error which will need to be fixed.

Comment: You might also have to do something about the previous button. I see it doesn't show on the first page currently. You will need for it to be there but we can hide it with jQuery when it's on page 1, and show on subsequent pages. I will update my answer. You will need to make your previous button show all the time and add `style="display:none;"` to it.

Comment: Any jQuery version from about 1.6+ to latest 1.x should work.

Comment: Excellent John - got it doing the transition now, but we're not pulling in the next set of records each time, rather it is going back to the first set of 4 (I tested using ?Page=5). I also cannot seem to pull the language code from the scroll page, but that is okay as I can pull it from the scrolllatest page instead, as it stays constant.

I have uploaded a zip containing both files so you can see the full code. http://www.stratusinternational.com/upload/scroller/scrollerpages.rar

Comment: Have also added a line to pull the Page Number and Language in both pages - you will see the results at http://stratusinternational.com/scrolllatest.asp

Comment: In scrolls.asp you only need to return the table so you need to remove all the HTML, HEAD and SCRIPT area, and you also need to close your TABLE at the end of the script. See http://pastebin.com/7iL4NCa4. In scrollatest.asp I made a mistake with some of the JavaScript so it never leaves page 1. I have updated answer and see also http://pastebin.com/tupbUwJJ. Looks like you sorted out the language code well.

Comment: Thanks John. Got it working now, apart from the navigation buttons - think something went wrong with them, so have removed them for now. Client would still like them in there though. You have been a real star with all of this.

I had to change the data: part and I think that is where it went wrong! Had to change it the way I did though for it to pass the data to my query - without the change, it still kept going back to page 1!

Comment: If the next button wasn't working I think I see why. I had `UpdatePage(-1);` instead of `UpdatePage(1);` in the next button handler. I have updated the answer.